# Can a pandas df have numbers for columns that can be selected?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some data that looks like this in a pandas dataframe called ratings:

```
           rating                                                        
id       10063204 10073140 10077387 10091371 10124740 10136418 10146903
user_id
10003869      NaN      8.0      NaN      NaN      3.0      NaN      NaN
10022889      NaN      NaN      1.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

user_id's for rows, id's for columns and ratings as the values.
I have looked ALL over the internet and could not find an answer to this:

The columns that I'm using are numbers, 8 digits, currently they are ints (or floats, either way they're not strings) but I can't search or select them given an id unless they're strings.

Using loc/iloc don't work because they're column numbers.

For example, say I have the id: 10146903 (last column here but the real dataset has thousands of columns, so I wouldn't know it's column number just given this id) but I have thousands of columns and I want to pull the column for that specific id.

Will I have to change them to strings to search them like that? Or is there a way to find it if they're not strings? I'd rather not convert them to strings because they'll just have to become ints again later.

I was thinking I could use these numbers as indexes for columns but seems you can only do that on rows.

I was trying to just do this:

```
specificID = ratings[10146903]
```

But that just returns

```
KeyError: 'the label [10146903] is not in the [index]'
```

Comment: Your example doesn't show any column called 99841034, so it's unsurprising that wouldn't work.  Can you show a short self-contained example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Did you try `ratings.loc[:,10146903]`?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I was copy/pasting from my code. I changed it above to look more consistent with the data in the post. The actual data has thousands of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double square brackets to denote an array of indices, e.g. `df[[j,j]]` then `i` and `j` can be integers.

Example:

```
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4),  columns=[1234, 56, 7, 890])
>>> df
       1234      56        7         890 
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
1  1.867558 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357
2 -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
3  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674
4  1.494079 -0.205158  0.313068 -0.854096
5 -2.552990  0.653619  0.864436 -0.742165
6  2.269755 -1.454366  0.045759 -0.187184
7  1.532779  1.469359  0.154947  0.378163
>>> df[[56]]
         56
0  0.400157
1 -0.977278
2  0.410599
3  0.121675
4 -0.205158
5  0.653619
6 -1.454366
7  1.469359
```

Comment: THANKS!! That must be written somewhere but I could not find it for the life of me

Comment: I know, these pandas selections are tricky. You can find some simple examples in the [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pandas/1751/indexing-and-selecting-data).